# finitely presented representations

Tags: ct.category-theory, homological-algebra, modules, quivers

Let Q=(V,E) be a direct graph where V is the set of all its vertices and E denotes the set of all its arrows. $X$ is called a representation of Q by modules if it is a functor from Q to R-Mod. i.e. $X(v)$ is an $R$-module for each $v\in V$ and for an arrow $a:v\to w$ in Q, $X(a):X(v)\to X(w)$ is a homomorphism of $R$-modules (for a composition of arrows $h=ab$, we have $x(h)=X(a)X(b)$).

It is proved that $(Q, R-Mod)$, the category of representations of Q by R-modules, is equivalent to the category of RQ-modules whenever RQ is a path ring associated to $Q$. Hence this a locally finitely presented category.

Question: Describe finitely presented objects n this category precisely. Is it true to say that $F$ is finitely presented if and only if  $F(v)$ is finitely presented for each vertex $v\in Q$?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, your question is phrased like homework, so you should rephrase it to make it appropriate for this forum.

Concerning the question, the answer is no. Take $Q$ to be a loop (only one vertex $v$). Then the category of representations is equivalent to the category of $R[x]$-modules (the equivalence sends a representation $F$ to $F(v)$, where multiplying by $x$ corresponds to applying the homomorphism induced by the loop arrow). The $R[x]$-module $R[x]$ is finitely presented but the corresponding representation $F$ satisfies $F(v)=R[x]$, which is not finitely presented as an $R$-module.